# gdb print command doesn't work for only one variable.. for the other works. The breakpoints are correct. why?

Tags: c, security, debugging, gdb

i need the address of a particular array, i obtained other array's addresses with success but in this one i got stuck.. here is the main code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  string[0] = 0;
  char polpetta[]="secret-file";
  char buf[50] ;

  printf("me Can I read the secret file?! \n\n");
  if (argc > 2) {
    vuln(argv[1]);
    strcpy(buf, argv[2]) ;
  } else {
    printf("You forgot to read me!!!\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

ok i put the breakpoint after the first printf:

```
(gdb) b* 0x080485f3
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80485f3
(gdb) r 12 12
Starting program: /home/andrew/Desktop/Software-Security-Lab/rop/rop-vuln 
me Can I read the secret file?! 
Breakpoint 1, 0x080485f3 in main ()
(gdb) p &buf
$1 = (char **) 0xb7fb9ef0 <buf>
(gdb) p &polpetta
No symbol "polpetta" in current context.
```

ok i obtained with success the address of buf... but not the address of polpetta! so i tried with different methods:

```
(gdb) p $polpetta
$2 = void
(gdb) p &$polpetta
Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.
(gdb) p polpetta
No symbol "polpetta" in current context.
(gdb) info locals
No symbol table info available.
(gdb) p *polpetta
No symbol "polpetta" in current context.
```

what the hell?? i also tried to repeat this routine at different breakpoints inside the main function...
thanks for your kindness!

Comment: Since you never use `polpetta`, the compiler might have optimized it away.

Comment: @ScottHunter thanks for the answer but the problem remains.. i added the line : "printf("%s\n",&polpetta);" i put the breakpoint after that line but i cannot still retrieve the address of polpetta.

Comment: Are you sure you're putting the breakpoint where you think you are? Using an address instead of a function name or line in a file is an unusual choice.

Comment: How/where is the variable `string` defined? Maybe it triggered undefined behaviour. Also what flags do you use to compile your program?

Comment: @axelduch  it's a global variable! I put only the main function in this question not the whole code!

Comment: @Shawn yes I am sure because before the breakpoint as you can see, there is the string "can I see the secret file?" printed!  Before writing "b* addeess"  I've disassembled the main function!

Comment: What gets printed w/ your added `printf`?  Is the behavior different if you copy the first character of `argv[0]` into a character of `polpetta` before printing?

Comment: @ScottHunter i've tried to add those lines:        polpetta[0]= argv[0];
printf("%s\n",&polpetta);

Comment: the behavior is the same....   @axelduch i compile my program with those flags : -no-pie -m32 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -fno-stack-protector -zexecstack  (i need them in order to attack the program for class). i've also disabled the randomization with the following command : sysctl kernel.randomize_va_space=0

Comment: Have you tried adding the `-g` flag?

Comment: This might not change anything for your current project but it is important to note that the "-g" flag  should not be shipped in production, it's a debug flag

Comment: @axelduch thank you very much! Yes I understand it.. It makes sense!